# Error Installing ios-buildkit

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration

This morning i found this automation tool for iOS [here](http://maniacdev.com/2014/02/open-source-tool-for-easily-automating-ios-project-builds-from-the-command-line). It looks really interesting but unfortunately I got this error installing it:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'buildkit' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: buildbot, buildgap, buckit, build, build_47
```

I followed the instructions step by step. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the gem is incorrect.

`gem install ios_build_kit`

Is the correct gem name.

You might also want to check out [xcoder](https://github.com/rayh/xcoder)